# How do I start the GUI (Window Manager?) over VNC?

Tags: 10.04, window-manager, vnc

I have a netbook and a server, to both of which I installed the identical Ubuntu 10.04 LTS distribution. On the server, I had the foresight to install and enable the SSH server before disconnecting the monitor and keyboard and mouse. I then ssh'ed in and enabled the VNC server as well. Now I want the full server experience on the netbook, but when I VNC in, I am greeted with the displayed screen. (names have been redacted)

[image: image of vnc screen showing only one xterm]

How do I start the rest of the default Ubuntu GUI experience? (the toolbars at the top) ((is that the window manager?))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try editing the `xstartup` file:

```
vi $HOME/.vnc/xstartup
```

add following lines to the file

```
#!/bin/sh
unset SESSION_MANAGER
exec sh /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc
[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
vncconfig -iconic &
x-terminal-emulator -geometry 1280x1024+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &
x-window-manager &
```

Start vnc server:

```
vncserver -geometry 1280x1024 -depth 24
```

If you are accessing your remote machine, then remember to forward the ports of vncserver.

Comment: This doesn't display anything, but a blank desktop.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but doesn't exec sh cause all subsequent lines to be ignored?

Answer (score 7):

install xfce4 and use xfce4 session, gnome VNC Server on Ubuntu sometimes does not display correctly

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-core xfce4 firefox nano -y --force-yes
```

and use this xstartup file

```
#!/bin/sh
unset SESSION_MANAGER
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
startxfce4 &

[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
vncconfig -iconic &
```

Comment: This sounded extreme to me, but I was frustrated with my inability to get gnome to work so I tried it and it did *just work* and that's about what I need (in fact, I just need to be able to move a Window so I can see what's behind it...)

Answer (score 2):

Don't use VNC. It's a horrible solution. Go with something like X2go (http://www.x2go.org/) instead. It's easily installed, extremely much faster than VNC and it's more flexible, providing things like PulseAudio. It also has a Firefox plugin so you can run applications from the server directly in the browser, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I was frustrated with my inability to get gnome to work so I tried it like that

1. `sudo apt-get install xfce4`
2. modify `.vnc/xstartxup` like this
3. run vncserver
4. connect server via vnc viewer
5. I can see windows manager

**.vnc/xstartxup:**

```
#!/bin/sh

# Uncomment the following two lines for normal desktop:
# unset SESSION_MANAGER
# exec /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc
unset SESSION_MANAGER
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
/usr/bin/startxfce4 &

#[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
#[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
#xsetroot -solid grey
#vncconfig -iconic &
#x-terminal-emulator -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &
#/usr/bin/x-window-manager &
```